# Search an array, display results by relevance to query

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I'd like to perform a search in a javascript array, that displays all results in relevance to the query, something equivalent to the following SQL statement:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE input"
```

Here's an example:

```
var array = [];
array[0] = "Apple";
array[1] = "Apricot";
array[2] = "Pear";
array[3] = "Peacock";
```

Let's say my querystring is "ap", it would return results in the following order:

```
1. "Apple"
2. "Apricot"

query = "p"
result:

1. "Pear"
2. "Peacock"
3. "Apple"
4. "Apricot"

query = "r"
result:

1. "Apricot"
2. "Pear"
```

Is this possible in javascript? How?

Comment: I suppose you would have to write down your own function to do this. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: taffydb lets you use query objects instead of functions to filter data.

Comment: @dandavis taffy looks great, thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    var arr = [];
    arr[0] = "Apple";
    arr[1] = "Apricot";
    arr[2] = "Pear";
    arr[3] = "Peacock";

    var resultArr=[];
    var str='ap'//string to search

    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      if(arr[i].indexOf(str) != -1){
         resultArr.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }

  alert('search results:'+resultArr);
    //resultArr contains reults
```

Comment: worked great, thanks! Any idea how to display a maximum of 10 results?

Comment: If you want only  max 10 search results then  use script  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      if(arr[i].indexOf(str) != -1){
         resultArr.push(arr[i]);
         if(resultArr.length>=10){
           break;// get out from loop 
         }

      }
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [];
array[0] = "Apple";
array[1] = "Apricot";
array[2] = "Pear";
array[3] = "Peacock";

function searchArray(query){
    resultArray = [];
    for(var i=0;i<query.length-1;i++){
        var char = query.charAt(i);
        if(array[i].indexOf(char)!=null){
            resultArray.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

This is untested, just off the top of my head. But you should have the result you are looking for in resultArray